# How do I correctly perform CASE logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a "calculated" column base on "if...else" logic.
I've tried:

```
        x.ApplicationID
        ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,  x.CreateDate, GETDATE()) < 7 THEN 1
            WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,  x.CreateDate, GETDATE()) < 14 THEN 2
            WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,  x.CreateDate, GETDATE()) < 30 THEN 3
            ELSE 0
        END AS Prodleni
```

which raises an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Only 1 `else` (the last one). the multiple `when` is expected

Comment: Just remove the `ELSE`'s except the last (default/catchall). For future reference, T-SQL is pretty well documented: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only 1 else is needed. you need to use like below-

```
 x.ApplicationID
        ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,  x.CreateDate, GETDATE()) < 7 THEN 1
               WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,  x.CreateDate, GETDATE()) < 14 THEN 2
               WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,  x.CreateDate, GETDATE()) < 30 THEN 3
            ELSE 0
        END AS Prodleni
```

read more from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Comment: Statement formatting is perfect, but i cant understand `logic` in this , column will return value  3 for values between `0' to `30`, this `case` expression doesn't make any sense

Comment: I hv fixed the syntax issue.. logic is with the author. :)

Comment: @BHouse No, it will return the first condition it meets. So 6=1, 13=2, 29=3, 30=0.